# Exception migrating GWT to Ext GWT

Tags: gwt, extjs

Initially i have implemented GWT application, and later implemented some pages from Ext GWT, when i added the same Ext GWT pages to GWT application, and during compilation i get the following exceotion,. please help me to get this solved.

> Compile of permutations succeeded
>   [INFO] Linking into C:\devbox\mlp\Avior\workbox\fvp-ui\target\fvp-ui\foo
>   [INFO]    Link succeeded
>   [INFO]    Compilation succeeded -- 57.427s
>   [INFO] Compiling module de.mlp.avior.fvp.ui.MainPartner
>   [INFO]    Validating newly compiled units
>   [INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/devbox/mlp/Avior/workbox/fvp-ui/src/main/java/de/mlp/avior/fvp/ui/client/ExtAddPartner.java'
>   [INFO]          [ERROR] Line 15: No source code is available for type com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.form.TextField; did you forget to inherit a required module?
>   [INFO]          [ERROR] Line 40: No source code is available for type com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.form.LabelField; did you forget to inherit a required module?
>   [INFO]          [ERROR] Line 87: No source code is available for type com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.form.DateField; did you forget to inherit a required module?
>   [INFO]          [ERROR] Line 93: No source code is available for type com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.button.Button; did you forget to inherit a required module?
>   [INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/devbox/mlp/Avior/workbox/fvp-ui/src/main/java/de/mlp/avior/fvp/ui/client/ExtListPartners.java'
>   [INFO]          [ERROR] Line 19: No source code is available for type com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.grid.ColumnModel; did you forget to inherit a required module?
>   [INFO]          [ERROR] Line 26: No source code is available for type com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.grid.ColumnConfig; did you forget to inherit a required module?
>   [INFO]          [ERROR] Line 33: No source code is available for type com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.Style.HorizontalAlignment; did you forget to inherit a required module?
>   [INFO]          [ERROR] Line 62: No source code is available for type com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.store.ListStore; did you forget to inherit a required module?
>   [INFO]          [ERROR] Line 67: No source code is available for type com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.ContentPanel; did you forget to inherit a required module?
>   [INFO]          [ERROR] Line 72: No source code is available for type com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.layout.FitLayout; did you forget to inherit a required module?
>   [INFO]          [ERROR] Line 75: No source code is available for type com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.grid.Grid; did you forget to inherit a required module?
>   [INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/devbox/mlp/Avior/workbox/fvp-ui/src/main/java/de/mlp/avior/fvp/ui/client/Foo.java'
>   [INFO]          [ERROR] Line 172: No source code is available for type com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.DatePicker; did you forget to inherit a required module?
>   [INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/devbox/mlp/Avior/workbox/fvp-ui/src/main/java/de/mlp/avior/fvp/ui/client/PartnerBean.java'
>   [INFO]          [ERROR] Line 5: No source code is available for type com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.BaseModel; did you forget to inherit a required module?
>   [INFO]    [ERROR] An internal compiler exception occurred
>   [INFO] com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.InternalCompilerException: Failed to get 
>   JNode [INFO]  at 
>   com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.TypeMap.get(TypeMap.java:140)
>   [INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.TypeMap.get(TypeMap.java:127)
>   [INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.TypeMap.get(TypeMap.java:71)
>   [INFO]  at 
>   com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.BuildTypeMap.getType(BuildTypeMap.java:778
>   ) [INFO]  at 
>   com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.BuildTypeMap.access$000(BuildTypeMap.java:
>   100) [INFO]  at 
>   com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.BuildTypeMap$BuildDeclMapVisitor.visit(Bui
>   ldTypeMap.java:199) [INFO]  at 
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.traverse(LocalD
>   eclaration.java:237) [INFO]  at 
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ConstructorDeclaration.traverse(
>   ConstructorDeclaration.java:505) [INFO]  at 
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.traverse(TypeDec
>   laration.java:1239) [INFO]  at 
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.trave
>   rse(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:687)
>   [INFO]  at 
>   com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.BuildTypeMap.createPeersForNonTypeDecls(Bu
>   ildTypeMap.java:683) [INFO]  at 
>   com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.BuildTypeMap.exec(BuildTypeMap.java:547)
>   [INFO]  at 
>   com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.BuildTypeMap.exec(BuildTypeMap.java:537)
>   [INFO]  at 
>   com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaToJavaS
>   criptCompiler.java:550) [INFO]  at 
>   com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaScriptCompile
>   r.java:35) [INFO]  at 
>   com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:541)
>   [INFO]  at 
>   com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:495)
>   [INFO]  at 
>   com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:407)
>   [INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:215)
>   [INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:187)
>   [INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:159)
>   [INFO]  at 
>   com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:87)
>   [INFO]  at 
>   com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileT
>   askRunner.java:81) [INFO]  at 
>   com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:166)
>   [INFO]       [ERROR] : public class com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.form.TextField
>   [INFO]  extends Field
>   [INFO] /*   fields   */
>   [INFO] protected static [unresolved] 
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.impl.TextBoxImpl impl [INFO] protected 
>   [unresolved] java.lang.String emptyStyle [INFO] protected [unresolved] 
>   Unresolved type com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.core.El input [INFO] protected 
>   [unresolved] Unresolved type 
>   com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.form.Validator validator [INFO] private 
>   [unresolved] boolean allowBlank [INFO] private [unresolved] int 
>   maxLength [INFO] private [unresolved] int minLength [INFO] private 
>   [unresolved] boolean needsPreventDefaultMouseUp [INFO] private 
>   [unresolved] boolean password [INFO] private [unresolved] 
>   java.lang.String regex [INFO] private [unresolved] boolean selectOnFocus
>   [INFO] /*   methods   */
>   [INFO] public void ()
>   [INFO] [unresolved] protected Unresolved type 
>   com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.util.Size adjustInputSize() [INFO] 
>   [unresolved] protected void applyEmptyText() [INFO] [unresolved] 
>   public boolean getAllowBlank() [INFO] [unresolved] public int 
>   getCursorPos() [INFO] [unresolved] protected Unresolved type 
>   com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.core.El getFocusEl() [INFO] [unresolved] 
>   protected Unresolved type com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.core.El getInputEl() 
>   [INFO] [unresolved] public int getMaxLength() [INFO] [unresolved] 
>   public TextFieldMessages getMessages() [INFO] [unresolved] public int 
>   getMinLength() [INFO] [unresolved] public java.lang.String getRegex() 
>   [INFO] [unresolved] public boolean getSelectOnFocus() [INFO] 
>   [unresolved] public java.lang.String getSelectedText() [INFO] 
>   [unresolved] public int getSelectionLength() [INFO] [unresolved] 
>   protected Unresolved type com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.core.El getStyleEl() 
>   [INFO] [unresolved] public Unresolved type 
>   com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.form.Validator getValidator() [INFO] 
>   [unresolved] public boolean isPassword() [INFO] [unresolved] protected 
>   void onBlur(Unresolved type 
>   com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.event.ComponentEvent)
>   [INFO] [unresolved] public void onComponentEvent(Unresolved type 
>   com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.event.ComponentEvent)
>   [INFO] [unresolved] protected void onFocus(Unresolved type 
>   com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.event.ComponentEvent)
>   [INFO] [unresolved] protected void 
>   onRender(com.google.gwt.user.client.Element, int) [INFO] [unresolved] 
>   protected void onResize(int, int) [INFO] [unresolved] protected void 
>   removeEmptyText() [INFO] [unresolved] public void select(int, int) 
>   [INFO] [unresolved] public void selectAll() [INFO] [unresolved] public 
>   void setAllowBlank(boolean) [INFO] [unresolved] protected void 
>   setAriaState(java.lang.String, java.lang.String) [INFO] [unresolved] 
>   public void setCursorPos(int) [INFO] [unresolved] public void 
>   setEmptyText(java.lang.String) [INFO] [unresolved] public void 
>   setMaxLength(int) [INFO] [unresolved] public void setMinLength(int) 
>   [INFO] [unresolved] public void setPassword(boolean) [INFO] 
>   [unresolved] public void setRegex(java.lang.String) [INFO] 
>   [unresolved] public void setSelectOnFocus(boolean) [INFO] [unresolved] 
>   public void setSelectionRange(int, int) [INFO] [unresolved] public 
>   void setValidator(Unresolved type 
>   com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.form.Validator)
>   [INFO] [unresolved] public void setValue(D) [INFO] [unresolved] 
>   protected boolean validateValue(java.lang.String)
>   [INFO] /*   members   */
>   [INFO] public class 
>   com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.form.TextField$TextFieldMessages
>   [INFO]  extends Unresolved type 
>   com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.form.Field$FieldMessages
>   [INFO]  enclosing type : com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.form.TextField
>   [INFO] /*   fields   */
>   [INFO] private [unresolved] java.lang.String blankText [INFO] private 
>   [unresolved] java.lang.String maxLengthText [INFO] private 
>   [unresolved] java.lang.String minLengthText [INFO] private 
>   [unresolved] java.lang.String regexText [INFO] final [unresolved] 
>   TextField#RAW this$0
>   [INFO] /*   methods   */
>   [INFO] [unresolved] public void () [INFO] [unresolved] public 
>   java.lang.String getBlankText() [INFO] [unresolved] public 
>   java.lang.String getMaxLengthText() [INFO] [unresolved] public 
>   java.lang.String getMinLengthText() [INFO] [unresolved] public 
>   java.lang.String getRegexText() [INFO] [unresolved] public void 
>   setBlankText(java.lang.String) [INFO] [unresolved] public void 
>   setMaxLengthText(java.lang.String)
>   [INFO] [unresolved] public void setMinLengthText(java.lang.String)
>   [INFO] [unresolved] public void setRegexText(java.lang.String) [INFO] 
>   [INFO] [INFO] [INFO] [INFO] [INFO]
>   [INFO]          org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding
>   [INFO]       [ERROR] at ExtAddPartner.java(15): TextField txtfldNewTextfield = new TextField();
>   [INFO]          org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration
>
> ### [INFO]
>
> --
>   [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
>
> ### [INFO]
>
> --
>   [INFO] Total time: 2:38.172s
>   [INFO] Finished at: Wed Jun 29 11:22:48 IST 2011 [INFO] Final Memory:
>
> ### 15M/37M [INFO]
>
> -- [ERROR] Failed to execute goal 
>   org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.2.0:compile (default) on project 
>   fvp-ui: Command [[ [ERROR] C:\devbox\java1.6\jre\bin\java -Xmx512m 
>   -classpath 
>   C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-user\2.2.0\gwt-user-2.
>   2.0.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-dev\2.2.0\gwt-
>   dev-2.2.0.jar;C:\devbox\mlp\Avior\workbox\fvp-ui\src\main\java;C:\devb
>   ox\mlp\Avior\workbox\fvp-ui\target\generated-sources\gwt;C:\devbox\mlp
>   \Avior\workbox\fvp-ui\src\main\resources;C:\devbox\mlp\Avior\workbox\f
>   vp-ui\target\fvp-ui\WEB-INF\classes;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\de\ml
>   p\avior\fvp\fvp-model\1.2-SNAPSHOT\fvp-model-1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users
>   \kdel.m2\repository\de\mlp\avior\fw\model\fw-model-types\1.3\fw-model
>   -types-1.3.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\jexcelapi\
>   jxl\2.6.10\jxl-2.6.10.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\log4j\log4j\1.2
>   .14\log4j-1.2.14.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\joda-time\joda-time\
>   1.5.2\joda-time-1.5.2.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\de\mlp\avior\fw
>   \model\fw-model-persistence\1.3\fw-model-persistence-1.3.jar;C:\Users\
>   kdel.m2\repositor
>   y\org\aspectj\aspectjrt\1.6.9\aspectjrt-1.6.9.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\org\hibernate\javax\persistence\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api\1.0.0.Final\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-annotations\3.5.6-Final\hibernate-annotations-3.5.6-Final.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-commons-annotations\3.2.0.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\3.5.6-Final\hibernate-core-3.5.6-Final.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.6\antlr-2.7.6.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.1\commons-collections-3.1.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\xml-apis\xml-apis\1.0.b2\xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\javax\transaction\jta\1.1\jta-1.1.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-entitymanager\3.5.6-Final\hibernate-ent
>   itymanager-3.5.6-Final.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\cglib\cglib\2.2\cglib-2.2.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\asm\asm\3.1\asm-3.1.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\javassist\javassist\3.9.0.GA\javassist-3.9.0.GA.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-validator\4.1.0.Final\hibernate-validator-4.1.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\3.0.5.RELEASE\spring-orm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\3.0.5.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\3.0.5.RELEASE\spring-tx-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\3.0.5.RELEASE\spring-aspects-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context-support\3.0.5.RELEASE\spring-context-support-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\1.0.0.GA\validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar;C:\Users\kdel\
>   .m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.6.1\slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\de\mlp\avior\fvp\fvp-service\1.2-SNAPSHOT\fvp-service-1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\3.0.5.RELEASE\spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-user\2.2.0\gwt-user-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\r09\guava-r09.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\r09\guava-r09-gwt.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.6\commons-lang-2.6.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\3.0.5.RELEASE\spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\3.0.5.RELEASE\spring-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\3.0.5.RELEASE\spring-expression-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-asm\3.0.5.RELEASE\spring-asm-3.0.5.
>   RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\3.0.5.RELEASE\spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\3.0.5.RELEASE\spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\com\extjs\gxt\2.2.4\gxt-2.2.4-gwt22.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\com\gwtplatform\gwtp-mvp-client\0.5.1\gwtp-mvp-client-0.5.1.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\com\gwtplatform\gwtp-clients-common\0.5.1\gwtp-clients-common-0.5.1.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\inject\gin\1.5.0\gin-1.5.0.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\com\google\inject\extensions\guice-assistedinject\3.0-rc2\guice-assistedinject-3.0-rc2.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\com\gwtplatform\gwtp-dispatch-client\0.5.1\gwtp-dispatch-client-0.5.1.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\com\gwtplatform\gwtp-dispatch-shared\0.5.1\gwtp-dispatch-shared-0.5.1.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\com\gwtplatform\gwtp-dispatch-server\0.5.1\gwtp-dispatch-server-0.5.1.jar;C
>   :\Users\kdel.m2\repository\com\gwtplatform\gwtp-crawler\0.5.1\gwtp-crawler-0.5.1.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\htmlunit\htmlunit\2.8\htmlunit-2.8.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\xalan\xalan\2.7.1\xalan-2.7.1.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\xalan\serializer\2.7.1\serializer-2.7.1.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.0.1\httpclient-4.0.1.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.0.1\httpcore-4.0.1.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpmime\4.0.1\httpmime-4.0.1.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\org\apache\james\apache-mime4j\0.6\apache-mime4j-0.6.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.4\commons-codec-1.4.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\htmlunit\htmlunit-core-js\2.8\htmlunit-core-js-2.8.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\xerces\xercesImpl\2.9.1\xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\nekohtml\nekohtml\1.9.14\
>   nekohtml-1.9.14.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\cssparser\cssparser\0.9.5\cssparser-0.9.5.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\org\w3c\css\sac\1.3\sac-1.3.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.0.1\commons-io-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\com\google\appengine\appengine-api-1.0-sdk\1.4.2\appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.4.2.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\com\gwtplatform\gwtp-processors\0.5.1\gwtp-processors-0.5.1.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\com\google\inject\guice\3.0-rc2\guice-3.0-rc2.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\javax\inject\javax.inject\1\javax.inject-1.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\com\google\inject\extensions\guice-servlet\3.0-rc2\guice-servlet-3.0-rc2.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\aopalliance\aopalliance\1.0\aopalliance-1.0.jar;C:\Users\kdel.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-gin\1.0-r137\gwt-gin-1.0-r137.jar com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler -gen C:\devbox\mlp\Avior\workbox\fvp-ui\target.generated -logLevel INFO -style OBF -war C:\devbox\mlp\Avior\workbox\fvp-ui\target\fvp-ui -localWorkers 2 -draftCompile de.mlp.avior.fvp.ui.Foo de.mlp.avior.fvp.ui.MainPartner
>   [ERROR] ]] failed with status 1
>   [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
>   [ERROR]
>   [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>   [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>   [ERROR]
>   [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>   [ERROR] [Help 1] 
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionExceptio
>   n

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler says:

```
No source code is available for type com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.BaseModel; 
did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

So did you include the gxt in your .gwt.xml:

```
<inherits name="com.extjs.gxt.ui.GXT" />
```

Did you follow all steps in [gxt's tutorial](http://www.sencha.com/learn/Ext_GWT_Getting_Started_Tutorials)? Especially, is gxt's jar available to compiler? Since you are using maven to compile, did you [add gxt dependency to your pom.xml](http://www.sencha.com/learn/Tutorial%3aGWT_GXT_and_Maven_howto)?

Comment: Thanks lot, by simply adding that entry in *gwt.xml.. its fixed.

Comment: Hi, could you please tel me how i can provide the Css used by Ext gwt to GWT application. since i have added two files of Ext GWT to GWT application.